# CakePHP - Update Dropdown list

Tags: ajax, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I know you guys may have already answered loads of questions like this but I really need some help in my situation.
I couldn't find any answer that suits me.

I have 2 dropdown lists in a form (form id **MapInitForm**) :

- Zone : a list of my zones (id : **zoneSelect**), already populated
- Territory : a list of my territories (id : **territorySelect**)

I do have a **zone_id** in my Territories table.

So when I select one Zone, I need to get all associated Territories. And when I select one territory, I'll need to do some PHP stuff;

EDITED thanks to Mark's answer.

```
    $('#MapInitForm #zoneSelect').change(function(){
        var zone_id = $(this).val(); 

        var zone_id = $(this).val();
        var targeturl = $(this).attr('rel') + '?id=' + zone_id;
        $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: targeturl,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                },
                success: function(response) {
                        if (response.content) {
                                $('#territorySelect').html(response.content);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(response.content);
                        }
                },
                error: function(e) {
                        alert("An error occurred: " + e.responseText.message);
                        console.log(e);
                }
        }); 

    });
```

In my controller :

```
   public function zone_territories_ajax() {
    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');
    $id = $this->request->query('id');
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    $this->loadModel('Territory');
    $data = $this->paginate('Territory', array('Territory.zone_id =' => $id));
    // $data = $this->Territory->find('all', array('condition' => array('Territory.zone_id =' => $id)));

    $this->set('zoneTerritories', $data);
}
```

In my view :

```
   $url = $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'zones', 'action' => 'zone_territories_ajax'));

        echo $this->Form->create('Map');
        echo $this->Form->input('zone_id', array(
            'options' => $zones, 
            'empty' => '--- Select one ---', 
            'id' => 'zoneSelect', 
            'rel' => $url
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('zone_territory_id', array(
            'empty' => '--- Select one zone ---', 
            'id' => 'territorySelect', 
            ));
        echo $this->Form->end();
```

And finally in my zone_territories_ajax.ctp :

```
    if (!empty($zoneTerritories)) {
        $k = 0;
    foreach($zoneTerritories as $zoneTerritory):
        echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $zoneTerritory['Territory']['name'] . '</option>';
        $k++;
        endforeach;
   }
   else {
       echo '<option value="0">' . __('noOptionAvailable') . '</option>';
   }
```

In my console, I'm getting **undefined** for *console.log(response.content);*
But I'm getting the correct values for the selected zone (I see those in my console again) but nothing happens on the second dropdown list.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky, just a while back I wrote something about AJAX and CakePHP:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp

And in particular, you can see a full blown example of exactly that functionality here:
http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax_examples/chained_dropdowns

The code is linked at the bottom - [see github](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-sandbox/blob/master/Plugin/Sandbox/Controller/AjaxExamplesController.php)

Basically:

```
    $('#source').change(function() {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();

            var targeturl = $(this).attr('rel') + '?id=' + selectedValue;
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: targeturl,
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                            if (response.content) {
                                    $('#target').html(response.content);
                            }
                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                            alert("An error occurred: " + e.responseText.message);
                            console.log(e);
                    }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Did you look at the example and its source code? That should answer your question. Note the url of the controller involved.

Comment: I recommend doing it exactly as I suggest it in the blog post, example and the code that is available. than it will definitly work. And it is cleaner than what you are doing there (without json extension and stuff). Why $this->paginate()? What you want is a simple find(list). You might want to take a closer look at the examples and whats going on there.